# Solve a system of time dependent equations where the Unknown variables are time dependent functions

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have to solve a system of time dependent equations ( $eqf1,eqf2,eqf3,...eqm5,eqm6$, inside the equations there are known time dependent functions) where the Unknown variables ($f32,fe3,me3...f47,m47$) are vectors whose components are time dependent functions.

I have tryed to discretize the known time dependent functions inside the equations and I have express both equations and functions using a index $i$.

Then I have used [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) and [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
   Do[NSolve[{eqf1[i], eqf2[i], eqf3[i], eqf4[i], eqf5[i], eqf6[i], 
   eqm1[i], eqm2[i], eqm3[i], eqm4[i], eqm5[i], eqm6[i]}, {f32[i], 
   fe3[i], me3[i], f21[i], f10[i], m21[i], m10[i], f65[i], f54[i], 
   m65[i], f47[i], m47[i]}], {i, 0, imax, 1}]
```

This is an example of the equations I have:

```
   eqf6[i_] := R65.f65[i] + m6*g6[i] + fi6[i] == 0;
   eqm6[i_] := R65.m65[i] + Cross[(r66 + rc66), R65.f65[i]] +
               Cross[rc66, -f65[i]] + mi6[i] == 0;
```

$R65$ is a matrix and $r66, rc66$ are vectors; $g6[i], fi6[i], mi6[i]$ are known vectors whose components are time dependent; $f65[i], m65[i]$ are the unknown vectors whose components are time dependent functions.

In this way it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add some more details. If it isn't a differential equation, then NSolve[eqns,vars] may work where vars are just the variables with the time-dependence (e.g. f32[t]...)

Comment: I propose you to make a simplified example of your system of at maximum 2 equations that are principally like the ones you have in mind. Be specific. Then one may propose a solution valid in the general case.

Comment: Read the documentation for NDSolve.